# AngularJS equivalent of .html() to replace html chars

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html-entities

In jQuery, if you have a string with HTML in it you can process the HTML in it and replace special characters like '&' with '&'

```
var myString = 'Jack &amp; Jill';
var filtered = $('</div>').html(myString).text(); 
console.log(filtered); // outputs 'Jack & Jill'
```

I am writing a filter which would process HTML, but I'm depending on jQuery here, is there an AngularJS way to do it?

Here is my Filter code:

```
myApp.filter('filterHtmlChars', function() {
    return function(html) {
        return $('<div/>').html(html).text(); // how could I use AngularJS here?
    };
});
```

PS: I already know about ng-bind-html, what I'm trying to do is filter.

Comment: jqLite would do the trick if your main goal is to avoid loading jQuery: http://plnkr.co/edit/ce7g2p64JO4CahakupYt?p=preview However, I think you might be asking for a way that doesn't involve using a stand-in element altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use built-in jqLite instead:

```
.filter('filterHtmlChars', function(){
   return function(html) {
       var filtered = angular.element('<div>').html(html).text(); 
       return filtered;
   }
});
```

Then, in your view, `{{ foo | filterHtmlChars}}` outputs "Jack & Jill where `$scope.foo = 'Jack &amp; Jill'`

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ce7g2p64JO4CahakupYt?p=preview)